# Aiohttp async get request with proxy not working

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to do get requests with proxy support however, it simply does not hit that part of the code.

```py
proxy = f"http://{line}"
try:
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('https://www.google.com', proxy=proxy, timeout=1) as resp:
      text = await resp.read()
      print(f'Status: {text}')
      if(resp.status == 200):
        if(proxy not in working_proxies):
          working_proxies.append(proxy)
        print(f'{Fore.GREEN}[PROXY] {proxy} did work.')
      sum += 1
except(Exception) as e:
  print(f'Error: {e}')
```

It does not hit the await resp.text() and does not print it out at all.

Comment: first you should check what you have in variable `proxy` - maybe you forgot to remove `\n` at the end of line. Second: you should check if this proxy is really working - most free proxies are not working. Third: Google has big money to create complex system to detect bots/spamers/hackers and it may block you - and it may know all free proxies and blocks them. Better test it on other pages - ie. https://httpbin.org specially created to test requests. If you send request to  https://httpbin.org/get then it sends back all request's information (headers, cookies) as JSON data.

Comment: first you could run without `try/except` to see full error message.

Comment: code works if I use [tor network](https://www.torproject.org/) as proxy server. On Linux I can use it without `Tor Browser`. It needs extra code to reset `tor network` and get new IP  after every reset - and reset new few seconds.

Comment: the thing is, I want to use normal proxies from proxyscrape, It works perfectly when I do requests.get with the same proxies, however it doesn't work whenever I use aiohttp requests.

Comment: An example of how my proxies look
`102.223.208.3:8081`

And my code goes through all the lines in the text file and then makes the proxy URL be `http://102.223.208.3:8081` and then uses that as the proxy.

Comment: if you read from file then you may get line with `\n` (new line) at the end and it may looks correctly on screen but for `requests` it is wrong proxy. Standard method is to use `line = line.strip()` when you read from file.

Comment: I took few free proxies from list on [proxyscrape](https://proxyscrape.com/free-proxy-list) and they don't work. As I said before: most free proxies are not working - they closed or block by servers - so free list are useless.

Comment: some portals gives free access to tested proxies after registering. For example [scrapestack.com](http://scrapestack.com?utm_source=FirstPromoter&utm_medium=Affiliate&fpr=f9nhn) gives free `250 requests per month` - it is small but somethimes it can be enough. In every request it uses different `proxy` and you don't have to use it your request. See [documentation](https://scrapestack.com/documentation) for API.

Comment: Okay so some weird stuff, proxyscrape when I check those proxies with a 3rd party website (not proxyscrape), the proxies show as valid, or at least a few of them 100-200 of them. However with my tool not a SINGLE one of the proxies show up as valid, it throws an error on every single one of them.

Comment: did you try to use bigger `timeout`? Some servers may need more time to response correctly.

Comment: yes I did, yet it still doesn't work?

Comment: did you test it with different page? Maybe Google knows these proxies and they will never work with Google.

Comment: tested it with the httpbin site.